# How to find files with similar filename and how many of them there are with awk

Tags: linux, shell, file-io, awk

I was tasked to delete old backup files from our Linux database (all except for the newest 3). Since we have multiple kinds of backups, I have to leave at least 3 backup files for each backup type.

My script should group all files with similar (matched) names together and delete all except for the last 3 files (I assume, that the OS will sort those files for me, so the newest backups will also be the last ones)

The files are in the format `project_name.000000-000000.svndmp.bz2` where `0` can be any arbitrary digit and `project_name` can be any arbitrary name. The first 6 digits are part of the name, while the last 6 digits describe the backup's version.

So far, my code looks like this:

```
for i in *.svndmp.bz2 # only check backup files
do
    nOfOccurences = # Need to find out, how many files have the same name
    currentFile = 0
    for f in awk -F"[.-]" '{print $1,$2}' $i # This doesn't work
    do
        if [nOfOccurences - $currentFile -gt 3]
        then
            break
        else
            rm $f
            currentFile++
        fi
    done
done
```

I'm aware, that my script may try to remove old versions of a backup 4 times before moving on to the next backup. I'm not looking for performance or efficiency (we don't have that many backups).

My code is a result of 4 hours of searching the net and I'm running out of good Google queries (and my boss is starting to wonder why I'm still not back to my usual tasks)

Can anybody give me inputs, as to how I can solve my problems?

- Find `nOfOccurences`
- Make awk find files that fit the pattern `"$1.$2-*"`

Comment: *(I assume, that the OS will sort those files for me, so the newest backups will also be the last ones)* ... well, now, that'd not be a good thing to assume. Directory entries are returned in a arbitrary order, you must sort them yourself. Why don't you use whichever programming language you're familiar with?

Comment: @derobert That would be C# and I'd have to install Mono on the database server, which my employer is sure to be against.

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output as your description is ambiguous and we can't tell from the code what you want to do since if the code did what you want you wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one, an see if it does what you want.

```
for project in `ls -1 | awk -F'-' '{ print $1}' | uniq`; do
    files=`ls -1 ${project}* | sort`
    n_occur=`echo "$files" | wc -l`
    for f in $files; do
        if ((n_occur < 3)); then
           break
        fi
        echo "rm" $f;
        ((--n_occur))
    done
done
```

If the output seems to be OK just replace the echo line.
Ah, and don't beat me if anything goes own. Use at your own risk only.

Comment: It worked like a charm, deleted one too many dummy-backups, but thanks to your inputs I was able to complete my script. Thanks again!